# How to return the value of a function to an another object and print the value?

Tags: python, function

I am a beginner in python. I was trying to save the value returned by a function on an object and would like to print the object to see the values stored in that object. I wrote a sample code for part of my project already.
Code is attached. What i need to do is to save the value returned by "labels" (in code) to an object and print the value in labels.

```
def carlabels(carinfo):
    car_labels=[]
    num=60
    for (car,xy,orient,err,wl,sq) in carinfo:
        xy2= (int(xy[0]+r*math.sin(math.radians(orient))),int(xy[1]-r*math.cos(math.radians(orient))))
        car_labels.append((xy,xy2,str(tag)))
    return car_labels
```

Comment: `obj = carlabels(carinfo) ; print(obj)`  ?

Comment: @DeepSpace I tried this before, but its giving me a Name error:name 'carinfo' not defined.

Comment: So define it. If your function accept a parameter you'll need to provide it when calling the function. Keep in mind its name doesn't need to be `carinfo`.

Comment: Be careful with what you declare and what you use. `num`, `carinfo`are defined but not used whereas `taginfo` (in your `for` loop), `tag` and `r`  are not defined.

Comment: @DeepSpace But i have defined carinfo in later parts of the code.

Comment: @Nuageux . I have defined these values in later parts of the code.

Comment: @marcosidaho You should defined them before or gives them as argument of your function

Comment: @Nuageux, sorry i didnot understand.

Comment: @Nuageux, i was able to solve it.